# Find all row indices of dates that (when grouped) sum to a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame showing dates, purchases and re-purchases (minus sign)

```r
sales_month     purchase_sum
2019-01-01              256
2019-02-01              270
2019-02-01             -270
2019-03-01                0
2019-04-01               22
2019-04-01              -22
2019-05-01             -328
2019-05-01              328
```

I need to get indices/values of dates that have a purchase and re-purchase, e.g `(270, -270)` respectively

I expect the output of only those dates that have matching `purchase_sum` values:

`[1] "2019-02-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01"`

Code to generate the example:

```r
foo <- data.frame(sales_month = c("2019-01-01",
                                  "2019-02-01",
                                  "2019-02-01",
                                  "2019-03-01",
                                  "2019-04-01",
                                  "2019-04-01",
                                  "2019-05-01",
                                  "2019-05-01"),
                  purchase_sum = c(256, 270, -270,
                                   0, 22, -22, -328, 328),
                                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Be mindful that using `group_by`, `sales_month` column and `summarize` with `sum` may not work because some of the `sales_month` values may be 0 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using `dplyr` could be to `group_by` `sales_month` and absolute value of `purchase_sum` and select the dates which have more than 1 `sign` of `purchase_sum`.

```
library(dplyr)

foo %>%
  group_by(sales_month, abs(purchase_sum)) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(sign(purchase_sum)) > 1) %>%
  pull(sales_month) %>% unique

#[1] "2019-02-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01"
```

Answer (score 2):

With *base*:

```
with(aggregate(cbind(a=purchase_sum, b=abs(purchase_sum)) ~ sales_month, foo, FUN=sum), sales_month[a==0 & b>0])
#[1] "2019-02-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01"
```

selects dates where purchase_sum of the date is 0 and where abs(purchase_sum) > 0

Or you can sort it first and than compare if there is the same number at the same date with different sign.

```
foo <- foo[order(foo[,1], abs(foo[,2])),]
foo[c(FALSE, foo[-nrow(foo),1] == foo[-1,1] & foo[-nrow(foo),2] == -foo[-1,2]),1]
#[1] "2019-02-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(sales_month, purchase_sum) %>%
 distinct() %>%
 group_by(sales_month, purchase_sum2 = abs(purchase_sum)) %>%
 filter(n() == 2) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-purchase_sum2)

  sales_month purchase_sum
  <chr>              <int>
1 2019-02-01           270
2 2019-02-01          -270
3 2019-04-01            22
4 2019-04-01           -22
5 2019-05-01          -328
6 2019-05-01           328
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(sales_month, purchase_sum) %>%
 distinct() %>%
 group_by(sales_month, purchase_sum2 = abs(purchase_sum)) %>%
 filter(n() == 2 & row_number() == 1) %>%
 pull(sales_month)

[1] "2019-02-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01"
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah thank you for your remarks, I think I corrected it :)